# NoClassDefFoundError at runtime but class is in classes.dex, what givies?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have included a JAR file built from an Eclipse Android project, and I am referencing it in my Android Studio project like the following:

```
  compile files('libs/libraryproject.jar')
```

This works, and I am able to get auto-complete on code references. When I compile the APK everything is fine. I install and run, and then receive a no class def error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.canvas.CanvasContainer
            at com.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

However, when I unzip the APK, and use dexdump to view the classes.dex file, I see that the above class exists there.

Why then am I getting this class not found error at runtime?

**Update**:

Thanks to Chris's suggestion I noticed that earlier in the logs, my CanvasContainer class could not be linked due to it not being able to resolve  `interface 1990 'Lorg/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper$Cocos2dxHelperListener;'`. Pretty apparently it looks like my Cocos library code is not getting exported as part of my JAR.

Comment: What is the base class of CanvasContainer? any chances that it is some class from newer API than API on device?

Comment: A class with dependencies that can't be met at runtime will usually be dropped during installation.  If you uninstall the app, start up something collecting all of logcat and then install it again, you may find by searching through the result that there is mention of the issue buried in the logs generated during the installation process.

Comment: @ChrisStratton awesome point, if you would care to write that as an answer I would accept it. I now see that it is failing to link my class due to   not resolving interface 1990 'Lorg/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper$Cocos2dxHelperListener;'

Comment: @Selvin no but you were on the right track. The base class is a Cocos2d library class that is not being exported with my JAR file. The exception did not occur at compile time but at runtime due to the Cocos2d interface being missing.

Comment: sometimes the best thing to do is walk away from the problem for a night, listen to others on SO, and come back to it in the morning. If it wasn't for Chris suggestion it would have been a long time before I noticed the earlier linking failure.

Comment: Can you update with the full the stacktrace, it seems that you first describe one exception and in the last update you show another one, is that the final stacktrace?

Comment: @ChrisStratton you are officially my hero of the day. Now if you'd convert that comment to an answer, that'd be more awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class with dependencies which cannot be met at runtime will usually be dropped during installation, dex optimization or similar preparatory process.

If you uninstall the app, start up something collecting all of logcat and then install it again, you may find by searching through the result that there is mention of the issue buried in the logs generated during the installation/preparation process.

In this specific case here, an edit to the question indicates that the missing class itself had this type of unsatisfied dependency.

Comment: Miracle of miracles I logged in after years to find you had posted this only three days prior. Thank you for the help long back then!