# Android cordova plugin : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, noclassdeffounderror, cordova-plugins

My project is a Meteor application that has web users and mobile users (on Android and iOS). The reason why I need to have native applications with Cordova is because I need to use a specific library (that have been coded for Android and iOS). I've developped a cordova-plugin that is a bridge between my Meteor app and my library. I add this cordova-plugin with the command `meteor add cordova:{plugin_name@bitbucket_url/get/commit_hash.tar.gz}` . And then I run my app with `meteor run android-device --verbose` to build it on my Nexus 5.

When I look at the logs, I see no error, I also see that my jar files needed in my plugin are dexed:

```
-dex:
      [dex] input: /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
      [dex] input: /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] input: /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/com.google.playservices/google-play-services_lib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] input: /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/libs/anywaresdk.jar
      [dex] input: /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar
      [dex] input: /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/com.google.playservices/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar
      [dex] input: /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/libs/android-beacon-library-2.0.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-08b5b91946ca0289c8a6c6185a42d50c.jar <- /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-df56033b7c34d81e6100d180a5eb093f.jar <- /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/com.google.playservices/google-play-services_lib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed anywaresdk-ebcd8e8b201f2cf0e8f3947837f0a238.jar <- /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/libs/anywaresdk.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed android-async-http-1.4.4-1381083dec2d5e09b669d0f4d8aa7dbb.jar <- /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed google-play-services-63680b630aa52e827ce265766636b8d0.jar <- /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/com.google.playservices/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed android-beacon-library-2.0-b9ed313a0085ed5333e28cb89c1128cf.jar <- /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/libs/android-beacon-library-2.0.jar
      [dex] Found modified input file
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/raphael/WebstormProjects/skyshow/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build/classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (85 defs/107.7KiB) with dex B (207 defs/313.5KiB). Result is 292 defs/511.4KiB. Took 0.3s
       [dx] Merged dex A (292 defs/511.4KiB) with dex B (1 defs/0.4KiB). Result is 293 defs/652.5KiB. Took 0.1s
       [dx] Merged dex A (293 defs/652.5KiB) with dex B (72 defs/146.9KiB). Result is 365 defs/1077.0KiB. Took 0.1s
       [dx] Result compacted from 1634.2KiB to 597.6KiB to save 1036.6KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (365 defs/1077.0KiB) with dex B (40 defs/59.6KiB). Result is 405 defs/597.6KiB. Took 0.2s
       [dx] Merged dex A (405 defs/597.6KiB) with dex B (3422 defs/3053.3KiB). Result is 3827 defs/4345.6KiB. Took 0.4s
       [dx] Result compacted from 5460.2KiB to 3712.5KiB to save 1747.7KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (3827 defs/4345.6KiB) with dex B (67 defs/95.6KiB). Result is 3894 defs/3712.5KiB. Took 0.6s
```

But when my app starts after the build, after several seconds of execution I get the following error:

```
I/art     (18645): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<novom.anyware.anywaresdk.AWRAlarmBroadcastReceiver>
I/art     (18645): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<novom.anyware.anywaresdk.AWRAlarmBroadcastReceiver>
D/AndroidRuntime(18645): Shutting down VM
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime(18645): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18645): Process: com.id1yih4vymtz45gm5gsdh, PID: 18645
E/AndroidRuntime(18645): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lnovom/anyware/anywaresdk/AWRAlarmBroadcastReceiver;
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at novom.anyware.anywaresdk.AWRUtils.cancelAlarm(AWRUtils.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at novom.anyware.anywaresdk.AWRSyncService.stopPushService(AWRSyncService.java:413)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at novom.anyware.anywaresdk.AWRSyncService.onDestroy(AWRSyncService.java:420)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:2894)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "novom.anyware.anywaresdk.AWRAlarmBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.id1yih4vymtz45gm5gsdh-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    ... 13 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: novom.anyware.anywaresdk.AWRAlarmBroadcastReceiver
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        ... 15 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: novom.anyware.anywaresdk.AWRAlarmBroadcastReceiver
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):        ... 14 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18645):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I can see some logs that let me know that most of the classes in the `anywaresdk.jar` file are used successfuly before the error occurs with the `AWRAlarmBroadcastReceiver`. Just to make sure that the file was present, I unziped the jar file and I found the class file that is supposedly missing...

I also copied the apk that was installed in my Nexus 5 by meteor, unziped it and outputed the content of the file `classes.dex` with the android build tool `dexdump` and the class `Lnovom/anyware/anywaresdk/AWRAlarmBroadcastReceiver;` was listed in it.

Just to be sure my jar files were not corruped or something, I used them in a native Android app and they worked like supposed.

Why do I get a NoClassDefFoundError when I use them in my Meteor app via my Cordova plugin?

Comment: For anyone that has a similar issue, my problem was that this file had a dependency to support-v4 and I was not including it as a dependency in the `plugin.xml` of my cordova plugin. Thanks to Chris Stratton on that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686721/noclassdeffounderror-at-runtime-but-class-is-in-classes-dex-what-givies#comment45667148_28686721

Comment: You should write your comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that has a similar issue, my problem was that this file had a dependency to support-v4 and I was not including it as a dependency in the `plugin.xml` of my cordova plugin. Thanks to Chris Stratton on that post [NoClassDefFoundError at runtime but class is in classes.dex, what givies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686721/noclassdeffounderror-at-runtime-but-class-is-in-classes-dex-what-givies)