# Using .aar NoClassDefFoundError But Class Exists and is Dexed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dex, aar

I have several projects which I build to create an .aar. I then import this .aar into into Android Studio under /libs. The build.gradle file for this dependency looks as follows:

```
repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:+'
    compile(name: 'customApi-debug', ext:'aar')
}
```

Since the library is quite large I have set multiDexEnabled = true. Android Studio finds the library and autocomplete works. Building works fine too but running the app gives the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.companyx.android.api.ui.vision.metaio.MetaIoView
            at com.companyx.android.api.ui.vision.metaio.MetaIoView$$InjectAdapter.<init>(MetaIoView$$InjectAdapter.java:29)
```

I uncompressed and disassembled the .aar and dex files, respectively, and verified that the classes its complaining about actually exist. I've tried existing approaches for dealing with this problem but none of them worked.

Anyone else experienced this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There might be a verification error with the class. Look at the logs in logcat just after you install the application, while it is being odexed/oated, and see if there are any verification errors for that class.

Comment: There appear to be no errors during installation. What I did notice is that when I tap to go to the Activity that uses this source I get  I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.companyx.android.api.ui.vision.metaio.MetaIoView> several times right before I get my exception.

Comment: Yes, that means that there were some verification errors at install time. Take another look at logcat during installation :)

Comment: I can't seem to find any verification errors as they relate to this specific class. I found a couple of things that looked suspicious but I'm not sure if they are relevant to this problem: W/PackageParser﹕ Unknown element under <manifest>: meta-data at /data/local/tmp/com.companyx.pilot.noclassdefffoundtest.app Binary XML file line #22 and Unknown element under <manifest>: meta-data at /data/app/vmdl58152644.tmp/base.apk Binary XML file line #22. What keyword should I be looking for in logcat?

Comment: I just run into the same problem now. Sad that there's still no answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686721/noclassdeffounderror-at-runtime-but-class-is-in-classes-dex-what-givies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I run into the same issue. The fix is firstly to deploy the AAR file to a local maven (I utilized the plugin at https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin). Then I referenced to the local maven as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23045791/2563009. And eventually I declared the dependencies with a transitive option, like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile('com.myapp.awesomelib:awesomelib:0.0.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }
}
```

The error would be gone then.

Comment: @thuy-trinh Yes I am curious why too

Comment: Ohhhh man !!! i wasted my 1 day because of this , thanks !! :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was to change

```
compileOnly files('libs/mylibrary.aar')
```

in gradle to

```
implementation files('libs/mylibrary.aar')
```

and the error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

Just fyi, you can use a simpler syntax, which is valid too

```
 compile 'com.myapp.awesomelib:awesomelib:0.0.1'
```

Don't forget to omit the @aar thing at the end of the library name