# NoClassDefFoundError when using .aar file

Tags: android

I have a .aar file which I added to the libs folder and inside gradle I have

```
compile(name:'file-name', ext:'aar')
```

It compiles fine, but when I run it I get:

```
System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.app.foo.MUtil$3
```

Now this **MUtil class** is used inside the API method of the **.aar library** I use inside my app. I could see the MUtil class in the exploded-aar folder and I can even go to that class by <kbd>ctrl+click</kbd>  on its usage. But still  **`NoClassDefFoundError`**. Why?

**Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://clojars.org/repo/' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile('xx.xxx.xxxx:xx-xxx:0.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

task wrapper(type: org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.5'
}
```

Comment: this is probably happening due to not defining the correct proguard rules

Comment: @thepoosh But I don't think Proguard works for debug more over I have `minifyEnabled false` even for release.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .aar NoClassDefFoundError But Class Exists and is Dexed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857141/using-aar-noclassdeffounderror-but-class-exists-and-is-dexed)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.app.foo.MUtil$3
```

**[NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)**

> is thrown when the definition of class in not available during runtime .

**Finally**

> As per Javadoc NoClassDefFoundError can be thrown during linking or
>   loading of class file. It's denoted by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>   and comes when that particular class is present during compile time
>   but some how not available during runtime.

You can share your **build.gradle** . Most common error for `aar` file .

**Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync** & Try again .

**Edit**

```
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

Comment: `Verify that all required Java classes are included in the application’s classpath` How? I added the gradle code

Comment: @Housefly I had this problem when I included a library but it needed some other packages (e.g. it required the `gson` library). I did not know that as it was not written in the docs, but I asked the developers and they told me

Comment: @Housefly set up looks like perfect . Can you provide `xx.xxx.xxxx:xx-xxx` ?? Its secret ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes, the API is just provided for us and still in alpha stage.

Comment: @Nikola Looks like that is the problem. I just looked at the MUtil class imports are there are things which are missing. So I added them as well to  my gradle. But ideally what all dependencies it has, I have to add them to my gradle?

Comment: @Housefly You can add this .